# PyQt - sellectAll then Backspace to delete doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

I have a text editor which converts latin keybord keypresses to russian characters. I have reimplemented a QTextEdit class:

```
class MyTextEdit(QTextEdit):
def __init__(self, *args):
    QTextEdit.__init__(self, *args)

leftMousePressedSignal = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
rightMousePressedSignal = pyqtSignal(QPoint, QEvent)
mouseMovedSignal = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
mouseDoubleClickedSignal = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
keyPressedSignal = pyqtSignal(QEvent)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    pos = event.pos()
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.leftMousePressedSignal.emit(pos)
    elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
        self.rightMousePressedSignal.emit(pos, event)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
        pos = event.pos()
        self.mouseMovedSignal.emit(pos)

def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        pos = event.pos()
        self.mouseDoubleClickedSignal.emit(pos)

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
        self.keyPressedSignal.emit(event)
```

which I then use with the reimplemented keyPressEvent. So I had to reimplement the Backspace action as well:

```
    self.textEdit = MyTextEdit(self)
    ...
    self.textEdit.keyPressedSignal.connect(self.OnKeyPressed)
    self.actionSelectAll.triggered.connect(self.textEdit.selectAll)
    ...

def OnKeyPressed(self, event):
    key = event.key()
    txt = str(event.text())
    if key == Qt.Key_Backspace:
        if self.cursor.hasSelection():
            self.cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NoMove, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor, self.cursor.selectionStart() - self.cursor.selectionStart())
        else:
            self.cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.PreviousCharacter, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor, 1)
        self.textEdit.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
        self.textEdit.cut()
    elif key == Qt.Key_A and (event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier):
        self.textEdit.selectAll()
```

Now, if nothing's selected and I press Backspace, it deletes a single character to the left of the cursor. When a word is selected with a mouse and I press Backspace, it deletes the word. When a few words or the whole text is selected with the mouse and I press Backspace, it deletes the whole selection. So, it works fine. When I press a Select All button (or Ctrl+A) - it selects the whole text. But if I then press Backspace it only deletes 1 character to the left of the cursor, not the whole text.

I will greatly appreciate it if you cold tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reimplimenting selection and deleting behaviour, and why it's done not in `MyTextEdit`? If you just need to

> convert latin keybord keypresses to russian characters

you can only do this conversion, and let other work (selection, deliting, copying, etc) for `QTextEdit`.

I'd write it like this:

```
class TransliterationEdit(QTextEdit):
    latin_alphabet = unicode(string.ascii_letters)  # or dict with transliteration table

    def translateLetter(self, letter):
        return u'Ъ'  # just example, you need translate letter somehow

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        text = unicode(event.text())
        if text and text in self.latin_alphabet:
            self.insertPlainText(self.translateLetter(text))
            event.ignore()
        else:
            QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my rough implementation of `TextEdit` which converts Latin keypresses to Russian characters, hope it will help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from transliterator import SMTransliterator
# transliterator available at https://gist.github.com/1600988


class TransliterationEdit(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTextEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._transliterator = SMTransliterator()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        text = unicode(event.text())

        if not self._transliterator.add_letter(text):
            if text and self._transliterator.result:
                self.insertPlainText(self._transliterator.result)
            return QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)

        if self._transliterator.need_next:
            return  # skip it

        self.insertPlainText(self._transliterator.result)


if __name__ == '__main__':      
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TransliterationEdit()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

transliterator available at [gist](https://gist.github.com/1600988)

Comment: It's not a straight character for character transliteration, sometimes you have to press 2 Latin characters to get 1 Russian. That's why I'm doing this in the program, rather than the class. And if I don't re-implement all keys, all non-character keys (space, backspace, arrows etc.) get ignored.

Comment: @user665327, Ok, it's up to you where are you doing it, but it fits into  overridden `QTextEdit` class logic very well. It's easy to add support for 2 or more Latin keypresses. Non-character keys are ignored because you are not calling original `QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)`. If you want to separate classes, you will need to call `QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self.textEdit, event)` in `OnKeyPressed` to process non-Latin keys.

Comment: Are you saying I have to add another QTextEdit.keyPressEvent to my class in addition to my OnKeyPressed? And sorry, didn't understand how it's possible to add support for 2 key presses in TransliterationEdit class. How can you pass 2 separate events (key presses) to that class?

Comment: @user665327, No, I mean you should pass events to base class implementaion. Look at code that i've provided: when keypress is not Latin letter, i'm skipping it, by calling base class implementation `... else: QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)`, this allows to handle backspaces, select all, etc. About 2 key presses, I mean you need to implement this anyway (as I understand, you've done it already), `QTextEdit` haven't any methods to handle this, but it can be done in overriden class. I added my rough implementation to answer.